# Pass UserForm textbox value to cell

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

Community, I'm moderately new to excel.  I have a textbox called Box_One.  This has been set up on my userform.  All I want to do is have a cell value constantly equal whatever value is in the textbox.

I tried the following, but not quite sure how to implement properly

```
Home.Range("A2").Value = Box_One.Value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about using the Change event of your text box to run the code you want?  Something like

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Range("BU1").value = TextBox1.value ' specify the destination sheet and cell here
End Sub
```

I tested this real quick and it worked.

Comment: Again, I'm moderately new.  How and where do I implement that?

Comment: In the VBA editor, double click the textbox that contains the value you want to be constantly assigned to a cell, then a sub for this event (Change) with an empty body should appear and you just add the code you want to be executed every time the value of the textbox changes.  You can see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211341(v=office.11).aspx