# How to send the content from a Textbox on Userform to a Cell?

Tags: excel, vba

In an User form with the text box, a cancel button, and an Ok button. The ok button should send the text of the text box to the cell i want. The cancel is just to close.

I researched for it and all i got was this:

```css
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
GetData
End Sub
```

Which didn't work.

I'm not a good coder but I'm trying to build something to make my work easier, if someone could help i would really appreciate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519716/pass-userform-textbox-value-to-cell

Answer (score 0):

You need write the code in that command button click event..

```css
' ok button
Sub Button1_Click()
' replace the sheet name and range A2 or B2 with yours
Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub

' cancel button
Sub Button2_Click()
unloadme
End Sub
```