# VBA loop through textboxes and insert each box on different row

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I have much of this **form**

[image]

coded to what I want but I'm having difficulty with the most significant part of it. As shown in the image, the frame in the form with 30 textboxes is designed to have names entered in it. Each box has a different name. When I click "save data" button I want the names in the textboxes to be entered on the next available row on the worksheet, also in the image.

So, if the form has Bob, Joe, and Jane in the first three boxes, I'd want rows A:2-4 in the worksheet to be populated with each name respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass UserForm textbox value to cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519716/pass-userform-textbox-value-to-cell) Of course in this references question there is only one text box with one cell reference. But then again you will have to write 30 lines of code `-->` for each text box one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't (or don't want to) rely on textbox names, there are two possible ways out:

- **exploit `TabIndex`**

  if your textboxes inside "Individuals" frame have same `TabIndex` order as the cells you want to write their content into, then you could go as follows:

  ```
  Dim i As Long
  Dim strng As String

  With Me.Frame1 '<--| change "Frame1" to your actual "Individuals" frame name
      For i = 0 To .Controls.Count - 1
          strng = strng & GetTextBox(i).Value & " "
      Next
      Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Controls.Count) = Application.Transpose(Split(Trim(strng), " "))
  End With
  ```

  where you exploit the following `Function`:

  ```
  Function GetTextBox(tabId As Long) As Control
      Dim ctrl As Control

      For Each ctrl In Me.Frame1.Controls
          If ctrl.TabIndex = tabId Then Exit For
      Next
      Set GetTextBox = ctrl
  End Function
  ```

---

- **exploit `Top` and `Left` control properties**

  if your textboxes are properly vertically aligned (i.e. all texboxes in the same *row* share the *very same* `Top` property), then you could go as follows:

  ```
      Dim dict As Object
      Dim ctrl As Control

      Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
      With dict
          For Each ctrl In Me.Frame1.Controls
              .Item(Format(ctrl.Top, "000") & "-" & Format(ctrl.Left, "000")) = ctrl
          Next
      End With
      SortDictionary dict

      Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Me.Frame1.Controls.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
  ```

  where you exploit the following `Function`:

  ```
  Sub SortDictionary(dict As Object)
      Dim i As Long
      Dim key As Variant

      With CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
          For Each key In dict
              .Add key, dict(key)
          Next
          dict.RemoveAll
          For i = 0 To .Keys.Count - 1
              dict.Add .GetKey(i), .Item(.GetKey(i))
          Next
      End With
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: @Chad, did you get through it?

Comment: I figured the tab index would work best with what I have but I couldn't get it to work. Admittedly, I'm not sure how the two blocks of code relate.